# Error: "Can't set headers after they are sent"

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express

En un controlador estoy utilizando promesas por que realizo múltiples
consultas y quiero evitar tener una multitud de callbacks, si no encuentra 
un valor debe enviar un mensaje al cliente y no pasar a la siguiente 
promesa.

Este es mi código:

```
  var body        = req.body;
  var params      = req.params;
  var queryParams = req.query;

  var origin =  req.get('source-type') || req.get('user-agent');

  var orderData = new orderInterface(origin);
  orderData.setOrigin(origin);

  var historyData = new historyInterface();

  usersModel
  .findOne({ 'shopcart._id' : body.shopcart }, { 'password': false, 'credit': false })
  .exec()
  .then(function(user){

    var address = body.address;
    orderData.setUser(user.toObject());

    if(_.isObject(address)){
      address.user = user._id;
      return new addressModel(address).save();
    }else{
      return addressModel.findOne({ '_id': address }).exec();
    }
  })
  .then(function(address){

    orderData.setAddress(address);

    if (_.isEmpty(address.latitude) || _.isEmpty(address.longitude)){
        res.status(200).json(message.custom('No have coordinates in address'));
    }else{
      return establishmentsModel
      .findCoordinates([ address.latitude, address.longitude ])
      .populate('items.product')
      .exec();
    }
  })
  .then(function(establishments){

    var shopcart = orderData.shopcart;

    if(_.isEmpty(shopcart) || _.isEmpty(establishments)){
      var msn = 'Establishments not have coverage';

      if(_.isEmpty(shopcart)){
        msn = 'problem with the shopcart';
      }

      res.status(200).json(message.custom(msn));
    }else{

      shopcart.products.forEach(function(product){

        if(product.items){

          var item = establishments.items.id(product.items);

          if(item){

            orderData.addProducts(item, product.quantity);
            establishments.items[item.__index].buy      += product.quantity;
            establishments.items[item.__index].quantity -= product.quantity;

          }else{
            res.status(200).json(message.custom('produc outoff stablishments' + product.string()));
          }
        }else{
          res.status(200).json(message.custom('product without item' + product.string()));
        }

      });

      orderData.setEstablishments(establishments);
      return establishments.save();

    }

  })
  .then(function(establishments){

    var coupon = orderData.shopcart.coupon;

    var options = {
      code   : coupon || '',
      userId : orderData.user._id
    };

    return referralsModel.searchAndUse(options);
  })
  .then(function(result){

    var options = {};

    if(result.referrals){

      orderData.setDiscount(result.discount);
      historyData.setCoupon(result.referrals);

    }else{
      options.code  = result.coupon;
    }

    options.establishments = orderData.establishments._id;
    options.items          = orderData.items;
    return couponsModel.searchAndUse(options);

  })
  .then(function(result){

    if(result.promotion){
      historyData.setCoupon(result.promotion);
    }
    else if(_.isEmpty(result)){
      historyData.setItems(orderData.items);
      historyData.setCoupon(result.coupon);
    }

    if(result.discount){
      historyData.setDiscount(result.discount);
      orderData.setDiscount(result.discount);
    }

    orderData.addState('', new Date());
    orderData.addPay(body.pay);

    return new ordersModel(orderData.get('save')).save();

  })
  .then(function(order){

    historyData.setTime(orderData.order.create);
    historyData.setUser(orderData.user._id);

    if(historyData.get().save !== 0){
      orderData.setId(order._id);
      return historyModel.save(historyData.get());
    }else{
      if(params.userId){
        orderData.setId(order._id);
        order = orderData.get('send');
      }
        res.status(201).json(order);

    }
  })
  .then(function(history){
    var orderSend = orderData.get('send');
    res.status(201).json(orderSend);

  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  });
```

Cuando corro el test me envía el siguiente error dos veces:

```
[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]
[Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.]
```

Comment: El protocolo `Http` no permite modificar las cabeceras una vez se ha enviado información al cliente, aunque la información enviada sea mínima. Las cabeceras las puedes configurar mil veces... pero **siempre** antes de empezar el envio de datos al usuario. Revisa tu código no vaya a ser que en el momento de enviar el código de la página `res.status(x).json(...)` ya se haya hecho un envio anterior.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, estoy utilizando las condiciones para retornar la promesa o realizar el envío
del el mensaje, comprobé el resultado de las condiciones y están correctas, pero continua la siguiente promesa
y envía de nuevo el mensaje

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema que tiene tu programa se puede dividir en dos partes:

La primera es que no estas rompiendo adecuadamente la cadena de promesas. Estas van a continuar ejecutandose porque si tienes lo siguiente

```
 promise.then(function(resultado1) {
     if (condition) {
         hacer_algo();
     } else {
         return new Promise();
     }
 }).then(function(resultado2) {
     // ¿Si la condicion se cumple cual es el valor de resultado2?
 })
```

Si la condición se cumple lo que ocurrirá es que Javascript "agregará" una instrucción `return undefined` al final de tu bloque `then` según lo especificado en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function). Esta es una traducción:

> Por defecto las funciones devuelven `undefined`. Para devolver otro valor la función debe tener una instrucción return que especifique cuál es el valor que se va a devolver.

Tu solo devuelves un valor si la condición no se cumple; así que en caso que se cumpla el valor devuelto es `undefined` y esto para una promesa lo que significa es que se [**resuelve con el valor `undefined`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714460/break-promise-chain-and-call-a-function-based-on-the-step-in-the-chain-where-it). La cadena continuará ejecutándose hasta que termine o ocurra un error en cuyo caso se rechazará la promesa y se saltará a la rama correspondiente a los errores.

La segunda parte del problema es que partiendo de lo anterior posiblemente termines llamando varias veces a `res.status(200).json(..)` lo cual envía información al cliente porque [`res.json()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json) es equivalente a [`res.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.send) y este modifica las cabeceras de la respuesta asignandole `Content-Lenght`, `Content-Type` entre otras e inmediatamente envía una respuesta al cliente de ahí el error que te está imprimiendo.

Para que lo que estas tratando de hacer funcione tienes que usar una de las siguientes estrategias conocidas como *ramificar*. Puedes encontrar más información en los siguientes vínculos de SO en inglés.

[Bluebird promises and catch branching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387939/bluebird-promises-and-catch-branching)

[Proper way to skip a then function in q promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576862/proper-way-to-skip-a-then-function-in-q-promises)

[Break promise chain and call a function based on the step in the chain where it is broken (rejected)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714460/break-promise-chain-and-call-a-function-based-on-the-step-in-the-chain-where-it)

[How to properly abort a node.js promise chain using Q?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302271/how-to-properly-abort-a-node-js-promise-chain-using-q)

No obstante te pongo unos ejemplos de lo que quieres hacer.

**Ramificación**

```
promise.then(function() {
    if (condicion) {
        hacer_algo();
    } else {
        return promise2.then(function() {
            if (otra_condicion) {
                return promise3.then(function() {
                    otro_procesamiento();
                })
            } else {
                hacer_otra_cosa();
            }
       })
}).catch(function() {
   // Manejo de errores
});
```

Esto te crea cierta anidación pero es totalmente válido. Ten en cuenta que yo retorno varias promesas para solo tener que usar un catch para el manejo de errores. Para evitar la anidación en la ramificación puedes usar otras funciones. Esto es el equivalente de lo anterior.

```
function path2() {
    return promise2.then(function() {
        return path3();
    });
}

function path3() {
    if (otra_condicion) {
        return promise3.then(function() {
            otro_procesamiento();
        });
    } else {
        hacer_otra_cosa();
     }
}

promise.then(function() {
   if (condicion) {
       hacer_algo();
   } else {
       return path2();
   }
}).catch(function() {
    // Manejo de errores
});
```

Te vas a encontrar muchos ejemplos que usan el manejo de errores como control de flujo. A mí personalmente no me gusta mucho esa variante pero es completamente válida y usualmente la he visto traducida como *interrupción* o *ruptura*

**Ruptura**

```
promise.then(function() {
    if (condicion) {
        hacer_algo();
        throw new CustomError('mensaje identificador 1');
    } else {
        return promise2
    }
})
.then(function() {
    if (otra_condicion) {
        return promise3
    } else {
        hacer_otra_cosa();
        throw new CustomError('mensaje identificador 2')
    }
})
.then(function() {
    otro_procesamiento();
})
.catch(function(err) {
    if (err instanceof CustomError) {
        //if (err.message === 'mensaje identificador 1') {
        //    procesamiento posterior
        //}
        ...
    } else {
        // manejo de errores
    }
});
```

Comment: muchas gracias era exactamente lo que estaba pensado, me aclaraste mucho el tema de las promesas